# fancybox bug with trigger click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have to run fancybox with **trigger click** in my website, the problem that i discovered is that **with this method** if you click on elements inside the fancy box, the fancy box will close and appear again (**blinks**) .

**i want fancybox to prevent blinking when i click on elements inside the box and when i click on those elements i don't want to see any changes, thats all :)**

i created demo for this problem

http://jsfiddle.net/NhWLc/5/

```
<div id="a1">
  <p>Click on the box</p>
  <div class="r"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#a1').fancybox({   
    afterClose: function() {
      console.log('closed :( ');
    }
  }).click();// or .trigger('click');
});
```

any idea?

Comment: please you are not clear with your question, that what you want ?

Comment: i think the question is pretty much clear. i say when you execute fancybox with trigger click, you are not able to click inside of fancy box, because that will close that fancy box

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are making the selector `#a1` to act as both : the *trigger* and the *target* of fancybox therefore any click on itself will fire fancybox over and over again.

You would need to create another selector (the trigger) that targets the `#a1` element like

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#a1">triggers fancybox</a>
<div id="a1">
  <p>Click on the box</p>
  <div class="r"></div>
</div>
```

if you don't want the element `.fancybox` be visible, just add a `display:none` property

Then your js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        afterClose: function () {
            console.log('closed :( ');
        }
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LF27m/)**

**EDIT** : looking at you sample [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LF27m/2/), things could have been much simpler.

Having just this html

```
<div id="a1">
  <p>Click on the box</p>
  <div class="r"></div>
</div>
```

you could use this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox({
        href: "#a1"
    });
});
```

where no `click` is needed.

See you updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LF27m/3/)**

Comment: yep i think there is no other way. i modified your code to this and this works http://jsfiddle.net/LF27m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use this below html,add `id` to `<div>` and `<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#r"><div id="r" class="r"></div></a>`

```
<div id="a1">
    <p>Click on colors</p>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#r"><div id="r" class="r"></div></a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#g"><div id="g" class="g"></div></a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#b"><div id="b" class="b"></div></a>
</div>
```

[check here](http://jsfiddle.net/t6sq3/1/)

**----------------------Update----------------**

add afterShow()  to your jquery

```
$('#a1').fancybox({ 
    afterClose: function()
            {
            console.log('closed :( ');
            },
            afterShow:function()
            {
                $('#a1').click(function(){return false;});
            }

        }).click();
```

[Check again](http://jsfiddle.net/t6sq3/2/)

Comment: As i say before "i have to" open fancy box with trigger('click') so this is not the answer i looking for

Comment: this is smart solution but this will disable links inside the box

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it will be helpful or not just try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();   
            $('#a1').fancybox({ 
                afterClose: function()
                {
                    console.log('closed :( ');
                }
            }).click();// or .trigger('click');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom of an unclickable Fancybox overlay.  My client wanted to be able to link and automatically open up a certain Fancybox, like http://yoursite.com/#signup to open up an inline 'signup' Fancybox overlay.  Thanks to JFK I realized I was triggering and targeting the element with the ID of 'signup' rather than the element with the href attribute of '#signup'.  I got it to hook onto the last portion of the URL (i.e. #signup) and look up the matching 'a' href attribute, and to trigger a click on that element.

The demo below doesn't really help portray this, but you get to see the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/ca7no4yp/2/

The juicy bit:

```
$("a[href='#" + location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf('#')+1) + "']").fancybox().trigger('click');
```